# Tabbed-style UINavigationBar iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In a `UIViewController`, I'd like to show two tabs *in* a `UINavigationBar`.  I want the `UINavigationItems` to have similar behavior to `UITabBarItems` in a `UITabBarController`.  I want the NavBar to be visible in both view controller tabs, and I want to change the color of the tab title in the navBar if the tab is selected.

Is there a **simple and elegant** way to conveniently set text/selectedText or image/selectedImage and create `UINavigationItems` that have behavior similar to `UITabBarItems`, including the ability to have the nav bar space the items out evenly, just like in a `UITabBarController`?

It would be great if I could set this like it can be done in a tabBar: 
`UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:titleBlack selectedImage:titleRed];`

The goal is to have two tabs, that change color if they are selected and they would be evenly spaced across the bar.  I know I could do something simple like add two items to a navBarArray, but in order to have them spaced evenly across the bar for all screen widths, how would I do that?  Is there an elegant solution?

[image]

This example shows the first tab selected.  If I select the 2nd tab, I want Tab2 to be red and Tab1 to be black.  This is just text, but if I have to create an image to accomplish this, I will.

This question is **not a duplicate** of the many questions on S.O. that are referring to displaying both a `UITabBarController` and a `UINavigationController` in the same app.  This is different because I don't want a `UITabBarController`(I already have one that does something else- but I don't want to overcomplicate my question)- I just want to mimic this behavior, inside of a `UINavigationBar`.  Please please please do not tell me I shouldn't do it this way. That's just another way to say "I don't feel like helping you figure this out."

I've tried looking for clean, simple, elegant solutions.  I haven't found any.  A complete example would be appreciated.  Thanks =)

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use a UITabBar? what is it about a UINavigationController that you need? The navigation style is different between the two, so I'm wondering about how you expect the whole interaction to work.

Comment: My app has a UITabBarController already.  In one on the tabBar tabs, I want to mimic this same behavior in a NavBar, pinned to the top of the view, visible in both tab1 and tab2.  So if the tabs in the tab bar are called A, B, and C, I want tab C to have Tab1 and Tab2 in the Nav.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Why not then create another set of UITabBarControllers for each of the tabs?

Comment: Um, no.  That wouldn't allow me to have the same functionality I'm looking for- that would be terrible from a UX standpoint.

Comment: The reason I asked about the flow/interaction is because a nav controller is more suited to a sequential navigation, where you're just looking to toggle content based on a selection. I would say, build your Tab1 and Tab2 and a custom control pinned to the top of your VC which would control visibility of the other views. You mentioned UX but multi-level tab solutions are a bit of a UX quagmire to begin with.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm designing this based on the mockups my client gave me, that I must conform to.  I already brought up the issue with the client that it is weird from a UX standpoint to do this, but that's how they want it done.  I can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works well enough for me.  I created a custom label with 2 buttons and a view with a height of 1 to act as a separator.  I moved the `UITableView` down to pin the top of it to the `UIView`  You could easily add more buttons if you desire to have more than 2.

1. In the `viewDidLoad` method: `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`
2. In `viewDidAppear` method:  `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`
3. Create a custom `UILabel`, pin the leading, top, and trailing to the superView, and set the desired height constraint.
4. Create a custom `UIView`with a height constraint of 1 (to act as the visual separator between the custom Navigation Bar and `UITableView`, pin the trailing and leading edges to the superView, and pin the bottom space of the `UIView` to the bottom space of the custom `UILabel`.  Set the desired color for the separator.
5. Create two `UIButton`s, drag them into the label, and set these constraints:

   -pin the `UIButton` center Y's to the center Y of the UILabel

   -pin Button1's trailing to Button2's leading edge to each other *and to the horizontal center of the superview*

   -Pin Button 1's leading and Button2's trailing to the superView

   -Pin the top of the `UITableView` to the bottom of the `UILabel`
6. Set the `UIButton` color to change when selected, and set their targets as you would with any `UIButton`

Add any missing constraints in case I forgot to mention some.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]